# One way binding on Silverlight page - cancelling text modifications

Tags: silverlight

I am performing one way binding on an edit page. The user now wants a "Cancel Changes" button which would essentially rebind the form back to the values in the ViewModel.  How can I do this?  I tried to set the DataContext to null and set it back ot my viewmodel, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cache the original values. Use TwoWay data binding and look into implementing the [IEditableObject Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). .net RIA services entities implement this interface and when used with the DataForm control make these situations easier.

Comment: I can't change the architecture of my application to use TwoWay binding.  Why do I need to cache the original values?  They're still untouched in my ViewModel.